# By default, is the connection from PHP to SQLAnywhere secure or encrypted?

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

There is a requirement to connect to a remote server, over the internet, to a SQL Anywhere database.

SQL Anywhere has a number of PHP extensions, which allow for PHP to connect to the server via IP and a specific port - however, is the connection secure?

Is there an option that needs to be set on either the SQL Anywhere server or PHP web server to enable some sort of encryption? Or do we need to create a VPN tunnel between the two servers to make sure it is safe to send data over the internet?

Comment: mysql supports ssl-encrypted connections, but it's something you have to enable and isn't the default (since it needs a cert to work properly).

Comment: Thanks @MarcB - however it's a `SQL Anywhere` database, not `MySQL` - the SQL Anywhere documentation is labyrinthian, and as yet I've been unable to find anything concrete around security and encryption, even if it supports certificates...

Comment: d'oh, right... in any case: http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/ml-tls-s-3599504.html for web services, anyways...

Comment: Thanks @MarcB - that's a good sign if we can connect via web-services, not so good if we have to use TCP/IP... If the latter I guess a VPN tunnel is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, connections are unencrypted by default though passwords are never sent in the clear. You can use the ENCRYPTION connection parameter to indicate the type of encryption you want to use. TLS encryption is supported.

You don't say what version of SQL Anywhere you are using, but [here](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/81408d9a6ce2101493b9c3bd4a39e77e.html) are the v17 docs for the ENCRYPTION connection parameter. The usage of this parameter is pretty much the same going back to v10.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: The connection string is tcpip, does that make any difference?

Comment: Not really. The only other option is shared memory, which is limited to the same machine and doesn't support TLS. But since you're connecting to a remote machine, TCP/IP is what you need. Other than shared memory not supporting TLS, the protocol and the encryption type are unrelated.